# Deserialize json in Dictionary<double, double[]>

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I need to store and read a `Dictionary<double, double[]>` in json. All links I found so far handles `Dictionary<object,object>`, not the case where the value is an Array.
Is there a json-Syntax for this, like:

```
  "MyDic": {    
  "0":[90,270],
  "90":[0],
  "270":[0]    
  }
```

deserializes to `Dictionary<string,double[]>`, but

```
  "MyDic": {    
  0:[90,270],
  90:[0],
  270:[0]    
  }
```

is invalid json - obviously.

Do I need to save it as nested arrays, like

```
  "MyDic": [    
  [0,[90,270]],
  [90,[0]],
  [270,[0]]    
  ]
```

and convert it manually for serializing/deserializing?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of problem you are facing. Specifically "All links I found so far handles Dictionary<object,object> , not the case where the value is an Array" 

the Json structure you provided can be deserialized to Dictionary<string,List<double>> without manual conversion steps. From there we can convert it to Dictionary<double,double[]>

Comment: Your first JSON can be deserialized to `Dictionary<string,double[]>` and afterwards you could call `.ToDictionary(double.Parse, kvp => kvp.Value)`

Comment: the issue is basically to avoid any manual conversion. the first json couldn't be deserialized directly to `Dictionary<double,List<double>>` but  all Keys in json have to be `string` (obviously)

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific. Thanks for taking time!

Comment: Best way is to add sample data and then serialize.  Compare the sample serialized data to your actual input.

Comment: The first example should deserialize into `Dictionary<double, double[]>` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works OK:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<double, double[]>()
{
    [0] = new double[] { 0, 1, 2 },
    [1] = new double[] { 3, 4, 5 },
    [2] = new double[] { 6, 7, 8 }
};

string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(s);

dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<double, double[]>>(s);

foreach (var entry in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}: {string.Join(", ", entry.Value)}");
}
```

The output is:

```
{
  "0": [
    0.0,
    1.0,
    2.0
  ],
  "1": [
    3.0,
    4.0,
    5.0
  ],
  "2": [
    6.0,
    7.0,
    8.0
  ]
}
```

And:

```
0: 0, 1, 2
1: 3, 4, 5
2: 6, 7, 8
```

(Tested with `<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />`)

What issues are you having?

Comment: hmmm... you're right, obviously I had another error in my Type containing the dictionary... so my issue is debug-blindness... Thank you all for the effort!

Comment: So essentially a typo, as the original code should have worked.

Comment: @Charlieface Certainly sounds that way.

Comment: not even a typo... have complex type, and changing the format threw on debug... I only had in mind that change and forgot to proove it with other parts of the type... so really... a Blindness on my side :-D Thank you again :-)